# When do unmanaged DLLs get unloaded when used by C# web pages?

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, unmanaged

Our web application is written in C# ASP.Net on Windows IIS. We needed to interface with a third party unmanaged DLL that can only be used from C++. I created a C++ DLL wrapper and C# wrapper around that. It works pretty well but every few days the application pool needs to be restarted.
I'm wondering if there is a way to guarantee my DLL and the third party DLL get unloaded from memory once the C# web page is done with it. I know that Windows loads one copy of a DLL per process and multiple threads share it until the last thread using it frees it. I'm just a beginner at C# so I have no idea how it handles unmanaged DLL loadlibrary/freelibary.

Comment: Why do you care about their lifespan? Once they're loaded, it won't occupy excess space unless _something wrong_ is going on... are you suggesting _something wrong_ is going on?

Comment: The native DLL is likely not the problem. I rather think the managed DLL could be loaded multiple times using Assembly.LoadFrom() or related functions. Before restarting, have you taken a crash dump? Does the crash dump confirm the memory is used by DLLs? It's more likely that you have a regular memory leak.